# What is a polite response to 《很高興認識你》？

Tags: phrase, conversation, phrase-request

I usually say 《我也是》， but it feels like an awkward response, and maybe a bit cold.  Is there a common friendly or colloquial response? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

1. 我也是很高興認識你。
2. 請多多指教。(I'm not really sure how to translate this phrase.)
3. 能夠認識到你是我的榮幸。 (It's my honour / It's my pleasure to meet you here.) / (I'm delighted to meet you here.)

There's a lot of response for this. Just comment below if you have further problem.

Comment: Thank you! It sounds like option 3 is the most formal, is that right? 
As for the translation of 2, a literal translation might be 'please continue giving me comments'; would it be correct to interpret it that way? In English this one sounds sarcastic, so I wonder if it is the same in Chinese.

Comment: Yes, it is. As for the translation of 2, the translation would be something like..."I am willing to learn (something) from you."...It is formal, but usually used by the old generation...

Comment: (2) seems most natural to me....